# why webgl display texture like stripe

Tags: html, webgl

I am reading webgl programming guild and proceed to the chapter 5 where I learn how to display a simple texture on a quad.I copy the code from the book to my project . But I get the following [image: result]:

the code is simple.

```
shader.frag
    precision mediump float;
    uniform sampler2D u_Sampler;
    varying vec2 v_TexCoord;
    void main() {
        gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_Sampler, v_TexCoord);
    }
shader.vert

    attribute vec4 a_Position;
    attribute vec2 a_TexCoord;
    varying vec2 v_TexCoord;
    void main() {
        gl_Position = a_Position;
        v_TexCoord = a_TexCoord;
    }
```

This is the initTexture functions .

```
    function initTexture(gl, img) {
        let texture = gl.createTexture();
        if (!texture) {
            console.log('Failed to create the texture object');
            return false;
        }
        let u_Sampler = gl.getUniformLocation(gl.program, 'u_Sampler');
        if (!u_Sampler) {
            console.log('Failed to get the storage location of u_Sampler');
            return false;
        }
        gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, 1);
        gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
        gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGB, gl.RGB, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, img);
        gl.uniform1i(u_Sampler, 0);
        return true;


    }
```

this is the initVertex buffer function, the book use one buffer for both vertex coordinate and texture coordinate.The coordinate copied directly from the book . So it seems right.

```
function initVertexBuffers(gl) {

        var verticesTexCoords = new Float32Array([
            -0.5, 0.5,  0.0, 1.0,
            -0.5, -0.5, 0.0, 0.0,
             0.5, 0.5,  1.0, 1.0,
             0.5, -0.5, 1.0, 0.0,
        ]);
        let n = 4; // The number of vertices

        let vertexTexCoordBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
        if (!vertexTexCoordBuffer) {
            console.log('Failed to create the buffer object');
            return -1;
        }

        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexTexCoordBuffer);
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, verticesTexCoords, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

        let FSIZE = verticesTexCoords.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT;

        let a_Position = gl.getAttribLocation(gl.program, 'a_Position');
        if (a_Position < 0) {
            console.log('Failed to get the storage location of a_Position');
            return -1;
        }
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(a_Position, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, FSIZE * 4, 0);
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(a_Position);  // Enable the assignment of the buffer object

        let a_TexCoord = gl.getAttribLocation(gl.program, 'a_TexCoord');
        if (a_TexCoord < 0) {
            console.log('Failed to get the storage location of a_PointSize');
            return -1;
        }
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(a_TexCoord, 1, gl.FLOAT, false, FSIZE * 4, FSIZE * 2);
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(a_TexCoord);  // Enable buffer allocation


        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);

        return n;

    }
```

Comment: var verticesTexCoords = new Float32Array([
            -0.5, 0.5,  0.0, 1.0,
            -0.5, -0.5, 0.0, 0.0,
             0.5, 0.5,  1.0, 1.0,
             0.5, -0.5, 1.0, 0.0,
        ]);

Comment: I copy the code from the book. It seems correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error has been found in the following code. The second parameter should be assigned 2. webgl can't get the y coordinate , but thereby I learned how to draw this effect. Thank you for attention.
 gl.vertexAttribPointer(a_TexCoord, 1, gl.FLOAT, false, FSIZE * 4, FSIZE * 2);